# HTaccess not rerouting [CodeIgniter]

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have an application that works great when using the full url: sitename.com/index.php/foo/ but when I use HTaccess to remove the index.php it doesn't seem to work as expected. No matter which page I access I only see the home page. The htaccess file is doing something because without that line I get a 404 error.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|file-manager-files|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thoughts?

On my test site everything works just fine. Is this a server setting that needs to be tweaked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Codeigniter you want something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

If that is not working, check to make sure `$config['index_page'] = '';` and your .htaccess directives are set right:

```
<Directory "/some/absolute/path/htdocs">
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've done hundreds of Codeigniter installs on many OS configs and have always been able to get this to work, but I have had some issues occasionally where I had to get creative to get the `index.php` to disappear.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I'm still very naive with mod rewrite but this got everything working.

I still don't see why my previous htaccess file worked on one server and not the next but I'm happy that this solution does work.

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteCond is wrong. In first argument you have to use what to check. In example the requested URI, the script file name and so on. On the above example it looks like you try to compare $1 (dolar and one) to the right part of the Rewrite Condition :?

Comment: doesn't the condition mean: {match anything but not a,b,c}?

[CI example using same syntax](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: That Tutorial will help you solve your problem ;) http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html