# codeigniter path error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

i have turned off index.php in my codeigniter by .htaccess and also i left blank the index file in config.php
this is .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

i have a link to my controller function as 'cuser/authenticate' so the url looks like

```
mydoamin.com/cuser/authenticate
```

but it shows an error telling path not found
when i edit the above url to

```
mydomain.com/index.php/cuser/authenticate
```

it displays output

how can i tackle this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716273/htaccess-not-rerouting-codeigniter. Have a look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

These settings worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You may change `$uri_protocol` in the `application/config/config.php` from `"AUTO"` to `"REQUEST_URI"`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres straight copy/paste from my codeigniter installs, latest version..

set the following in your config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

create a .htaccess and fill it with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```